# Android camera application

Tags: android

I want a sample application for camera in android. If anybody developed any application please share with me along with source code. This will be very helpful for me.

Thanks in advance 
Praween

Answer (score 1):

Why not look at the official SDK sample?

http://google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#CRBM04-7BoA/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/CameraPreview.java